# NSString comparing in NSTimer "loop"

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, nstimer

I'm currently struggling with string comparing in Mac OS X

I want to check with a loop (in my case I chose a timer) if a file changes it's size.
To do so I do the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    fileSize = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] retain];
    fileSizeSrc = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] retain];

    fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    fileAtts = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:@"~/Desktop/test.txt" error:NULL];
    fileSizeSrc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [fileAtts fileSize]];
    [self startWatching:nil];
}
- (void)startWatching:(id)sender
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(checkForUpdates) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}
- (void)checkForUpdates
{
    fileAtts = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:@"~/Desktop/test.txt" error:NULL];
    fileSize = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [fileAtts fileSize]];
    if([fileSize isEqualToString:fileSizeSrc])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", fileSize);
        fileSizeSrc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileSizeSrc];
    }
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    [fileSize release];
    [fileSizeSrc release];
}
```

I can just check the size one time.
So when my code runs, it gives me an output and two seconds later (when the selector gets fired the second time) my program terminates with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

And when I try to invert the if() statement by changing to `if(![fileSize isEqualToString:fileSizeSrc])` it terminates immediately after launching.

I retained and then released the strings after the problem occurred the first time, because it dawned on me, that I have to do this.

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks a lot,
Greets, Julian.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use automatic retain counter(available in ios5):

you need to create a property that will retain your information(easy) or retain it yourself.

```
@interface ...
{
  NSString* _fileSizeSrc;
}

@property (retain)NSString* fileSizeSrc;

@end

@implementation ...
@synthesise fileSizeSrc = _fileSizeSrc;


...


@end
```

to set the property you need to write:

```
self.fileSizeSrc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [fileAtts fileSize]];
```

and two more things:

1. dont't forget to set the property to nil in `-(void) dealloc`
2. if you create a property - don't work with the variable directly.